# sapply function does not seem to work with df

Tags: r, function

This is a simplistic example of a much complicated dataset I have:

```
  record_id <-  c(1:10),
  date      <- as.Date(c("2018-09-01", "2018-12-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-06-01",
                 "2019-09-01", "2019-12-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-06-01",
                 "2018-11-30","2019-02-28"))
  
  ds <- cbind.data.frame(record_id, date)
```

This is the function I am using to create another variable:

```
arms_and_events_function <- function(d)
    {
        df <- data.frame(arm   = rep(1:3, each = 4), 
                         event = rep(1:4, 3),
                         start = as.Date(c("2017-09-01", "2017-12-01", "2018-03-01", 
                                           "2018-06-01", "2018-09-01", "2018-12-01", 
                                           "2019-03-01", "2019-06-01", "2019-09-01", 
                                           "2019-12-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-06-01")),
                          stop  = as.Date(c("2017-11-30",  NA,          "2018-05-31", 
                                          "2018-08-31", "2018-11-30", "2019-02-28", 
                                          "2019-05-31", "2019-08-31", "2019-11-30", 
                                          "2020-02-29", "2020-05-31", "2020-08-31")))
    
    matches <-  sapply(d, function(x) which(x >= df$start & x<= df$stop))
    paste0("arm", df$arm[matches], "_event", df$event[matches])
  }
```

```
  ds <- ds %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
      arms_and_events = NA,
      arms_and_events = as.Date(arms_and_events),
      arms_and_events = arms_and_events_function(date)
    )
```

When I do, I get this error:

> Error in df$arm[matches] : invalid subscript type 'list'

Can you help?

Comment: There is a typo up there, The object "stop" does not have a missing value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You don't need to initialise the column with `NA`.
- Pass the column that have dates in `arms_and_events_function`.

```
ds <- ds %>% dplyr::mutate(arms_and_events = arms_and_events_function(date))
ds

#   record_id       date arms_and_events
#1          1 2018-09-01     arm2_event1
#2          2 2018-12-01     arm2_event2
#3          3 2019-03-01     arm2_event3
#4          4 2019-06-01     arm2_event4
#5          5 2019-09-01     arm3_event1
#6          6 2019-12-01     arm3_event2
#7          7 2020-03-01     arm3_event3
#8          8 2020-06-01     arm3_event4
#9          9 2018-11-30     arm2_event1
#10        10 2019-02-28     arm2_event2
```

To handle missing values we can change the function to :

```
arms_and_events_function <- function(d)
{
  sapply(d, function(x) if(is.na(x)) NA else {
    inds <- which(x >= df$start & x<= df$stop)
    paste0("arm", df$arm[inds], "_event", df$event[inds])
  })
}
```

Comment: - If I don't initialize it with ```NA```, the dataset does not find it moving on.                              - The function should be run on the variable "date" and not "arms_and_events".

Comment: I updated the answer to pass `date` column in `arms_and_events_function`.

Comment: Okay, Ronak can you do me a favor and run the function on the "date" variable with couple values missing? I think that seems to be the problem. Thanks

Comment: See if you can find the solution with missing values of date

Comment: @MaleehaShahid Check the updated answer. You need to handle those missing values in `sapply`. Also I combined `paste0` and `sapply` step together.